# Android TimerTask crashes when called twice

Tags: android, timer, timertask

I'm calling my TimerTask (m_timer) upon a button click:

m_timer.schedule(m_progressUpdater, 0, 500);

Which kicks off my run method:

```
    @Override
    public void run() {

        //do some stuff
        progressBar.setProgress(currentProgress);

        if (progress >= 100) {
            handler.post(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    CompleteTask();
                }
            });
        }
    }
```

I can call this once and it works perfectly.  When I call it again, my app stops responding.  I'm thinking that I need to cancel the task in my CompleteTask() method, but I've tried cancelling both the TimerTask and the Timer, and it still crashes.  Anyone know what the problem might be?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried creating new TimerTask instance for the second call? And by the way, don't cancel the timer otherwise it will cancel all of its task. And what did the log say?

Answer (score 0):

When you reschedule a Timer, it throws:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: TimerTask is scheduled already
```

It seems that you can only use a timer for once.

In order to reschedule a Timer, you need to simply create a new instance of it, each time. like the following:

```
// if you have already started a TimerTask, 
// you must(?) terminate the timer before rescheduling it again.
if(m_timer != null)
    m_timer.cancel();

m_timer = new Timer();
m_progressUpdater = new myTimerTask();
m_timer.schedule(m_progressUpdater, 0, 500);
```